# Passing Large Data to View

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

What is the best way for loading large amount of data to view from controller? Or is there better approach than I'm currently doing? I currently have this code on my application. I just got 5k data on a table and it is already slow.

Controller

```
public function index() {
 $questions = Question::paginate();
 return view('admin.questions.index', compact(['questions']));
}
```

View

```
@foreach ($questions as $question)
 // datatable
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be paginating the data. You aren't passing a limit to the paginator.

```php
$questions = Question::paginate(20);
```

In your code, you aren't paginating the data. Secondly, you don't need to pass an array to `compact()`. Do this:

```php
return view('admin.questions.index', compact('questions'));
```

If pagination isn't intended, then it isn't the size of the data that's being passed to the view. Instead it is the time that is taken up by SQL queries while the data is retrieved from the database.